# PHP.ini to configure MySQL

Tags: php, ini, termux

I need php.ini code which will configure MySQL, BTW I am curious why without php.ini it throws error in mysqli_connect(), what **key=value**'s should be in .ini file so that I can work with database.
Additional information

I'm on termux

MySQL is running on port 3306,

PHP code for running http server

`php -t ./ -S 127.0.0.1:8080 -c ./`

Comment: I was not down voting, but I was using this option: "This question ....... **it is unclear**  ...... " .  Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There does not exist an option to configure MySQL in php.ini.   There are only options to configure how PHP accesses MySQL, which does not change the configuration of MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your setup, you may need to specify the full path to your php.ini:

```
php -t ./ -S 127.0.0.1:8080 -c /path/to/php.ini
```

Don't forget to uncomment `mysqli` in php.ini:

```
extension=mysqli
```

Also database configuration:

```
mysqli.default_host = 127.0.0.1
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_user = your_mysql_username
mysqli.default_password = your_mysql_password
```